Torque on current loop: caused by magnetic force on charge or by interacting external magnetic field with induced field
The torque on a current loop is explained by the interaction of an external magnetic field on the moving charges. But in this proces the magnetic moment of the current loop is introduced too. However the magnetic moment of the current loop is also a representation of the induced magnetic field. So the question I have is whether the torque is caused by the interaction of the two magnetic fields or only the result of the magnetic force on the moving charge. Or maybe I miss something else ?
